# Json Parsing data linux

Tags: json, parsing

hello i need to parse data from https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=node and put them inside bash shell so when a user ask for company it brings the info for company. I tried something like that

curl -s  https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=node | jq.

jq '.select["company"]' positions.json

but it keep saying me :jq: error: Cannot index array with string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the result base on specific company then you can use `select` filter in jq:

```
jq '.[] |select(.company == "companyName")'
```

And if you want to produce valid JSON array then you can wrap the filter with `[]`

```
jq  '[ .[] |select(.company == "companyName")]'
```

For whole bash script `run.sh companyName` you can do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=node | jq "[ .[] |select(.company == \"$1\")]"
```

You can try it interactively here: https://repl.it/repls/PortlyOffbeatCoin

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters

Comment: ty and if i want to take users input from command line? and find the exact CompanyName? like ./exersise.sh companyName and bring me back the whole company json

Comment: i replaced with this jq  '[ .[] |select(.company == "companyName")]' and nothing happened 
 jq  '[ .[] |select(.company == "Autodesk")]' positions.json

Comment: In the current set, I also haven't found any record from Autodesk. If you want only partial match then you can replace the `== "companyName"` with `| contains("partialName")`

Comment: ty a lot its working fine and if i want from user 2 variables? like ./ Location Company

Comment: If you want more variables then you can just use them as `$2` `$3` .... To compose the condition you need to use `and` or `or` for the condition. 
`jq  '[ .[] |select(.company == "Playco" and .title =="Engineering Manager")]'`

Comment: and last one and its done if i want to take 2 variables and bring from json title and description that match them